# How to count top 30 most common values in a dict in python

Tags: python

**I need to find 30 most common, please help me.** i try to using counter too but isn't work

```
import re
import string


frekuensi = {}
doc= open('doc-1.txt', 'r')


teks = doc.read().lower()
regex=r'\b[a-z]{4,20}\b'
find = re.findall(regex, teks)

for kata in find:
    hitung = frekuensi.get(kata, 0)
    frekuensi[kata] = hitung + 1

daftarf = frekuensi.keys()
for kata2 in daftarf:    
    print  kata2,  frekuensi[kata2]
```

Comment: Lookup the Python `Counter` object

Comment: I don't think `[^stopwords]` does what you think. It matches any single character that's not an `s`, `t`, `o`, `p`, `w`, `r`, or `d`.

Comment: Already Answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303619/how-to-count-top-10-most-common-values-in-a-dict-in-python