# Aggregation for List in Python

Tags: python, function, oop

I have a list. I am using Counter as below.

Here, I need to agregate the counting of movie names according to years.

```
listt = [['1',  '1995'],

['2',  '1993'],

['3',  '1992'],

['4', '1993'],

['5',  '1995'],

['6', '1995'],

['7',  '1996'],

['8', '1993'],

['9',  '1992'],

['10',  '1992'],

['11',  '1995'],

['12',  '1994'],

['13',  '1995']]


c=Counter(listt[0:][3])
```

Edited:

In this listt, I count movies names (like 'Toy Story','Jumanji') according to years (like'1995')

Expected result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93caG.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate"? Could you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: I edited question, also added expected result. Thank you!

Comment: I think the expected result is wrong. It should be:
`[('1995', 5), ('1993', 3), ('1992', 3), ('1996', 1), ('1994', 1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a `comprehension list` to `reduce` each entry to just its `year` (as you really don't care about neither the `name` nor the `genre`), and then using that as input for the `Counter`.

Finally, you can take advantage of the `most_common` method:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303678/5745962
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```py
movies_years = [x[3] for x in listt]

c = Counter(movies_years)

print(c.most_common(5))
# Output: [('1995', 5), ('1993', 3), ('1992', 3), ('1996', 1), ('1994', 1)]
```