# Count every word in a text and arrangement with any number and how to clean useless symbols in text and print with count

Tags: python, count, keyword, search-keywords

how i can make my Wikipedia output with count all words in this text and arrangement them with the top 10 most existing words and print them without any symbols?

```
import wikipedia

wikipedia.set_lang("en")
a = wikipedia.page("bitcoin")
words = a.content

print(words)
```

Comment: [How to remove punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725620/2308683) + [Find most common elements with count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303678/2308683)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the var words is a string, you can use nltk lib to split your string in a list of words, and then, perform your tasks.
Something like that:

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

words_list = nltk.word_tokenize(words)
words_frquence = FreqDist(words_list)
words_count = len(words_list)
words_unique_count =  len(set(words_list))
```

Now, to remove undesired words or symbols, you will need to apply a func in your string, try that:

```
import re

def nomalize(string):
    clean_string = re.sub(r'Ø|\+','',string) #add '|your symbol' to remove more symbols

    return clean_string
```